# How to print a 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am not sure how to print this 2D array. I am getting consistent errors in Visual Studio 2013. Every time I try to run it, it breaks and sometimes stops responding. If you see any other errors please let me know. Thank you for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_STUDENTS = 12;    // Number of students
const int NUM_QTRS = 4;         // Number of quarters

bool fillArr(double gpa[][NUM_QTRS]);
void averaging(double gpa[][NUM_QTRS], double avg[][12]);
void print(double avg[][12]);

int main()
{
double gpa[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_QTRS]; // Array for 12 students, each with 4 quarters      
// define a 2D array called avg, which is 2 rows x 12 columns 
double avg[2][12];

// read from file and fill array with students gpas
if (!fillArr(gpa))
    return 1;

// Calculate average gpa for each student and store the student ID and average gpa of each student
averaging(gpa, avg);

// print the student ID and average gpa
print(avg);

// search for a student by ID
//search(avg);

// sort students by GPA
//sort(avg);
//print(avg);

return 0;
}

///// fill in the function definition below each description

// fillArr: read in from the file gpa.txt to fill the gpa array
bool fillArr(double gpa[][NUM_QTRS])
{
// open file
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("gpa.txt");
if (!inFile)
{
    cout << "Error opening gpa.txt/n";
    return false;
}

// read data into gpa array
for (int row = 0; row < NUM_STUDENTS; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < NUM_QTRS; col++)
    {
        inFile >> gpa[row][col];
    }
}
inFile.close();
return true;
}

// averaging: calculate and store the ID and average gpa of each student in avg array
void averaging(double gpa[][NUM_QTRS], double avg[][12])
{
double total = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < NUM_STUDENTS; row++)
{
    total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_QTRS; i++)
    {
        total += gpa[row][i];
    }
    avg[row][12] = total / NUM_QTRS;
}
}

// print: print the student ID and average gpa of each student
void print(double avg[][12])
{
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
cout << "Student ID" << "\tAverage GPA" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        cout << avg[i][j];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why don't you use std::vector instead - it's so much easier :)

Comment: You could have discovered the error yourself by starting with a simpler case: create a 2x3 array with hard-coded values and try to print *one row*.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is

```
double avg[2][12];

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << avg[i][j] << "\t" << i + 1 << avg[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This for-loop is for an array that looks like this

```
double avg[12][2];
```

Reverse the for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        // print array
        cout << avg[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when I try to run the program after the fixes it is still not working.

Comment: My apologies. By that I mean when I go to run it, one of two things occur: the entire IDE stops working or I get a bunch of random numbers and a prompt to "abort".

Comment: Well. I cant know what actual changes you have done. You should probably upload it to pastebin.com and link it in your original post, or just update your original post with the new code.

Comment: I have done nothing, but delete my code and replaced it with your suggestion. I will update my original post with the new code.

Comment: You really should learn how to debug. In anycase, the problem is this - if (!fillArr(gpa)) return 1; This always happens and closes the program. Figure out why.

Comment: I suppose I should, which is why I was apprehensive about taking this course in the first place. Anyways, thanks for the help you have provided.